# def python error repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Although I'm entering a numerical value, it's still giving me an error. I dont know why this is happening.. help someone?

```
def is_string(s):
    rate = input(s)
    try:
        str.isalpha(rate)
        print('There was an error. Please try again. Make sure you use numerical values and alpabetical. ')
        return is_string(s)  #ask for input again
   except:
        return rate
ExRate = is_string('Please enter the exchange rate in the order of, 1 '+Currency1+' = '+Currency2)

def is_string2(msg):
    amount = input(msg)
    try:
        str.isalpha(amount)
        print('There was an error. Please try again. Make sure you use numerical values. ')
        return is_string2(msg)  #ask for input again
    except:
        return amount
Amount = is_string2('Please enter the amount you would like to convert:')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Read the documentation for [`isalpha()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) and you'll probably spot the error.

Comment: Which part of your `try` clause are you expecting to throw an error? Printing "There was an error" is insufficient to break from a `try` statement.

Comment: @Ben The OP's not even doing that since he's throwing away the result and expecting it to throw an exception for no reason knowable by man since that's not what the method does and there's no sane reason to expect it would.

Comment: I am trying to make sure that only numbers should be accepted for the variable ExRate, and everything else, especially string(letters) must be rejected.

Comment: @Jemini Then the thing to do is `try: amount = int(raw_input(...))` if anything. I'd also catch `ValueError` specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def get_int(prompt, error_msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print(error_msg)


rate = get_int(
    'Please enter the exchange rate in the order of, 1 {} = {}'
        .format(Currency1, Currency2),
    error_msg="Rate must be an integer")
amount = get_int(
    'Please enter the amount you would like to convert:',
    error_msg="Amount must be an integer")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're using exceptions, when you should be using just if statements:

```
def is_string(s):
    rate = input(s)
    if str.isalpha(rate):
        print('There was an error. Please try again. Make sure you use numerical values and alpabetical. ')
        return is_string(s)  #ask for input again
    else:
        return rate
ExRate = is_string('Please enter the exchange rate in the order of, 1 '+Currency1+' = '+Currency2)

def is_string2(msg):
    amount = input(msg)
    if str.isalpha(amount):
        print('There was an error. Please try again. Make sure you use numerical values. ')
        return is_string2(msg)  #ask for input again
    else:
        return amount
Amount = is_string2('Please enter the amount you would like to convert:')
```

Comment: I tried if statements, but it didn't work for my code as a whole as I'm trying to create a currency converter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the try statement, and I don't think you should be using isalpha(). isnumeric() tests for numeric validity. isalpha() will return false for a string like "%#-@".

```
while True:
    s = input("Enter amount: ")
    if s.isnumeric():
        break
    print("There was a problem. Enter a number.")
```

Comment: **-1** for unpythonic parentheses

Comment: Fixed. Code is now more pythonic.